# CSS3PIE border-radius does not compute :(

Tags: css3pie

Hey all. I've done tons of searching and still nothing. My element has the following CSS and the PIE.htc file is definatly in the correct folder. Still no curvey corners in IE6-8 :(

```
#nav {
width:500px;
border:2px solid #eee;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px; 
behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
position:relative;
z-index: 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Check that your PIE.htc file is being served with the correct HTTP content-type header. It needs to be "text/x-component", but some servers do not have this set up correctly and send something like "text/plain" or "text/html" instead; IE will ignore the behavior file if this is the case.

More suggestions can be found at http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/